# Is it correct to omit ''I'' in my sentence?

Tags: personal-pronouns

Is it correct to omit the personal pronoun?

> I previously activated (a substance) it but also **(I)** made it without activation.

Sorry for the incomplete question.

Comment: Please give the exact full sentence or sentences you want to ask about. Mark them as quotes please. Please also say why you think "I" can be omitted, or why you are unsure.

Comment: It's entirely a stylistic choice whether to "delete" the second instance of the subject ***I*** in your "parallel construction" context. The actual choice made has no effect on the meaning (idiomatically it's a bit unlikely, but you could in principle repeat the word ***previously*** without affecting the meaning).

Comment: I use the software Grammarly , and it chose without '' I '' and I do not understand it.

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting to make this question clearer. However, the example sentence is still pretty messy, so I recommend fixing that. You'd probably be able to get better answers then.